# How to Search In cassandra?

Tags: search, cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index, bigdata, database

i wanna to search in **cassandra** database.
After much research, I found

> **Stratio’s Cassandra Lucene Index**

Is there another way to simple search on Cassandra?
I mean a simple search query something like in Mysql

I've used this query but his conclusion was **wrong**

> select * from users where uname > 'sa' allow filtering;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you'd want to perform a text search on a non PRIMARY KEY column.

If that's the case, you could use a [SSTable Attached Secondary Index (SASI)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) that would allow to exactly search as you wrote. Specifically, you'd need to create a **CONTAINS index** to perform inequality searches on text fields. You need **Cassandra 3.4 and later**.